# Convert the query parameter to Date Datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api

We are creating an API that receives two input parameters which will be used in the Query for selecting datafrom the Database. Out of the two input parameters one is the Date.So our API call will be `/api/DataReturn?id=56&DOB='01-Jan-2016'`
I am planning to get the both input parameters in string format and convert them

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM,string SUBMITDATE)
{
  DateTime submit_date = DateTime.Parse(SUBMITDATE.Trim()).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TGSDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
  using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
            var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where ROOM = " + ROOM +"and SUBMITDATE =" +"'"+submit_date+"'";
```

It throws error saying `The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context`. I am not sure if I am doing them right

Comment: `using namespace System.Globalization;`

Comment: I added the System.Globalization now it is throwing `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'`

Comment: Try DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: You can't assign a string to to a DateTime.  You're taking the result of DateTime.Parse, converting it to a string then trying to assign it to a DateTime.

Comment: @RickS I am not getting we would be doing that.Iam trying to convert them in to Date datatype of format dd-MMM-yyyy because in oracle have them as the above format so we can use them in the Select query

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't _have_ a format (in either C# or Oracle) - you specify the format when you _display_ it.  So 1) don't call `ToString` on the DateTime if the Oracle field type is `Date` and 2) add parameters instead of string concatenation when creating your command.

Comment: I would also argue that the type of the C# parameter `SUBMITDATE` should be `DateTime` instead of string as well. You could then strip off any time component by using `DateTime submit_date = SUBMITDATE.Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Globalization` namespace to resolve `CultureInfo` issue. Then use `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
DateTime submit_date = DateTime.ParseExact("01-Jan-2016", "dd-MMM-yyyy", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
DateTime submit_date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Parse(SUBMITDATE.Trim()).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: I am getting the runtime error `FormatUserException was unhandled by user code`

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Parse("01-Jan-2016".Trim()).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

Comment: I am getting the input parameter as string here . Iam trying to convert them in to Date datatype of format dd-MMM-yyyy because in oracle have them as the above format so we can use them in the query.